# Historical Forecast or Observed Weather Data Source

Tags: api, weather

I'm looking for an API that provides recent, 3-hourly temperatures... either observed or forecasted.  To be clear, I'm looking for data from the past... like 'yesterday'.

Free or paid is fine. International or US only is fine.  Lookup by long/lat, zip, city doesn't matter either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking for an API that provides recent, 3-hourly temperatures... either observed or forecasted. To be clear, I'm looking for data from the past... like 'yesterday'.

I don't know of an API for historic weather data. "3-hourly" observations are often referred as *Syno* hours. For historic data, other than for model validation, 99% of the time only observed data is used. Unless otherwise needed, in general you want surface observation data.

In the US, the NCDC (National Climate Data Center)'s [Climate Data Online](http://www7.ncdc.noaa.gov/CDO/cdo) is likely your best source. The data is gratis, but with some (potential) usage restrictions.

Comment: I was able to find historic weather data for sites outside the US (and for free) on the NCDC site, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the public data from [NOAA's Global Summary of the Day public data FTP](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/gsod/), but you have to read the data format convention and build a script to connect and parse the data needed.

Have a look at the readme.txt file in the same FTP-folder, maybe you will find how to use this service.